# Where is the missing space?

Tags: disk-usage

I made a fresh install of Ubuntu on a 120 gb ssd and added some services (next cloud, Plex media server, etc) and all the data are located on other hard drives.

Suddenly the other day i got low on storage warning with over 100 gb in use. However looking into disk analysis, it shows that my system including home directory is only using half as much at most.. where is that missing space?

I don't know where to start looking for an answer so any help would be greatly appreciated

Disk space usage total:

[image: Disk space usage total]

Space used by folder:

[image: Space used by folder]

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                    1,6G  4,4M  1,6G   1% /run
/dev/sda5                109G   88G   16G  86% /
tmpfs                    7,9G  2,0M  7,9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p1           234G   99G  123G  45% /media/ssdnvme
/dev/sda2                512M  4,0K  512M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/md0                 7,3T  1,7T  5,6T  24% /media/raid0
tmpfs                    1,6G  240K  1,6G   1% /run/user/1000
//192.168.87.154/public  3,6T  201G  3,4T   6% /media/share
```

Comment: Please edit your question and copy/paste the output of `df -h`. Use [code fences](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) so formatting is preserved.

Comment: Are you running Docker containers?

Comment: Possibly written to a mountpoint...while unmounted.

Comment: @matigo i have installed docker but I'm not running any containers yet. It's how I found out i ran out of space.

Comment: @user535733 how do I check if that's correct? And how do I free that space?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This issue was resolved.
On this device i am running NextCloud. the Data directory of NextCloud is not visible when using disk management utilities or even manually checking every folder size. I moved Data directory to another hard drive and now things are back to the way they are supposed to be.